# Whats Wrong with this MySQL Script?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT @cnt := COUNT(table_name) 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_schema = 'TAA' 
   and table_name = 'Clients';

IF (@cnt > 0) THEN
  INSERT INTO `ClientsBAK` SELECT * FROM `Clients`;
END IF;
```

I get a syntax error at `IF(@cnt > 1) THEN` error 1064

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: How are you attempting to run this?  Ideally it should be in a stored procedure.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to test if there is more than 1 table matching your criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE BackupClients()
BEGIN

    SELECT @cnt := COUNT(table_name)
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'TAA'
    AND table_name = 'Clients';

    IF @cnt > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `ClientsBAK` SELECT * FROM `Clients`;
    END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL BackupClients();
```

I think you also want `IF @cnt > 0` instead of `IF @cnt > 1`, so I changed that for you.

Comment: Correct- I had been playing with the code and left that typo in.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can only use IF like that in routines (functions, triggers, stored procedures).